# Program does not call proper method, keeps looping back to first menu. (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, user-input, nested-loops

Ok, I have a small program that acts as a contact list. It is constructed from a 2d array, and it takes user input to populate it with 10 total contacts; so, the array is 10 rows and 4 columns that consist of first name, last name, phone number, and age. 
There is a menu that gives the user the option to 1) add a contact, 2) remove a contact, 3) display contacts, and 4) exit the program. I know it may look like a crude, brute force approach, but it is requested that we do not use anything but what we have learned thus far, which does not include methods such as ArrayList, LinkedList, Collections, HashMaps, etc. 
My problem is that the program works fine until after I remove a contact. When I'm given the menu again, and I want to re-add a contact, it just loops back to the menu. It has to be some sort of small syntax error, but I'm not sure where. I will show the code, as well as the output to give an idea of where it starts to mess up. 
*Note: I'm not asking for code per se, but suggestions and guidance to make me realize where I'm going wrong.

Code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactList {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ContactList ();
}

    public ContactList () {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] contactList = new String[10][4];


        System.out.println("Welcome to your Contact organizer.");
        System.out.println("You can store " + contactList.length + " contacts. " );
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice from the list below: ");
        System.out.println();

        while(true){
            System.out.println("1: Add a Contact"); //the user options
            System.out.println("2: Remove a Contact");
            System.out.println("3: Display your Contacts");
            System.out.println("4: Exit this program");

            int userSelection = input.nextInt();

            switch(userSelection) {
                case 1:
                    addContact(contactList);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    removeContact(contactList);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    displayContacts(contactList);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
private void addContact(String contactList[][]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++) {
        if(contactList[i][0] == null) {
            System.out.print("Enter the contact's first name: ");
            contactList[i][0] = input.nextLine().trim(); //.trim() eliminates any accidental white spaces

            System.out.print("Enter the contact's last name: ");
            contactList[i][1] = input.nextLine().trim();

            System.out.print("Enter the contact's phone number: ");
            contactList[i][2] = input.nextLine().trim();

            System.out.print("Enter the contact's age: ");
            contactList[i][3] = input.nextLine().trim();
            break;
        }
    }
}//end add method
private void removeContact(String contactList[][]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first name of contact you wish to remove: ");
    String deleteFirst = input.nextLine().trim();
    System.out.println("Enter the last name of contact you wish to remove: ");
    String deleteLast = input.nextLine().trim();
    for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < contactList[i].length; j++) {

            if(deleteFirst.equals(contactList[i][0]) && deleteLast.equals(contactList[i][1])) {
                System.out.println("Contact successfully removed. \n \n");
                contactList[i][0] = null;
                contactList[i][1] = null;
                contactList[i][2] = null;
                contactList[i][3] = null;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}//end remove method
private void displayContacts(String contactList[][]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < contactList[i].length; j++) {
            if(contactList[i][j] == null) {
                contactList[i][j] = (" "); //if user displays before all contacts are entered, it will display blank rather than null null null, etc.
            }
            System.out.print(contactList[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}//end display method
}//end class
```

I know the removeContact method may look horrible, but it was the only way I knew how to delete an entire row. I keep thinking I should make a new array in that method, but I don't know how just yet.

Here is the output:

```
    Welcome to your Contact organizer.
    You can store 10 contacts. 
    Please enter your choice from the list below: 

    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    1
    Enter the contact's first name: John
    Enter the contact's last name: Doe
    Enter the contact's phone number: 1234567
    Enter the contact's age: 34
    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    1
    Enter the contact's first name: Joe
    Enter the contact's last name: Bob
    Enter the contact's phone number: 4567890
    Enter the contact's age: 30
    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    3
    John Doe 1234567 34 
    Joe Bob 4567890 30  --contacts display just fine so far



    --I know there are a lot of spaces since technically there is 
      still data here, albeit blank spaces. Perhaps I need to make it a 
      new array each time something is added? I'll have to figure out
      how to do that. For now, it looked far better than: 
      null null null null
      null null null null 
      etc...




    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    2
    Enter the first name of contact you wish to remove: 
    Joe
    Enter the last name of contact you wish to remove: 
    Bob
    Contact successfully removed. 


    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    3
    John Doe 1234567 34 --output displays contact removed









    1: Add a Contact         --and this is where is begins to mess up. 
    2: Remove a Contact        Why now? 
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    1
    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    1
    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    1
    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    3
    John Doe 1234567 34       --I can still display contacts. ????









    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    1
    1: Add a Contact
    2: Remove a Contact
    3: Display your Contacts
    4: Exit this program
    4
    Goodbye.                 --and I can exit. I just can no longer add.

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Downvoted? Seriously? And for no reason? Ok, I guess a Q and A forum isn't actually a Q and A forum. Seems legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a problem here:

```
    if(contactList[i][j] == null) {
            contactList[i][j] = (" "); //if user displays before all contacts are entered, it will display blank rather than null null null, etc.
        }
```

I changed it to where it will only display the contacts if the contact is not null, as shown here:

```
    if(contactList[i][j] != null) {
                System.out.print(contactList[i][j] + " ");
            }
```

I am now able to return to my menu and add another contact. I would prefer that the output didn't leave an empty space, but I will figure that out on my own since it's irrelevant to my original post.

Though I don't know exactly WHY this problem was occurring (since I received no answers or comments, only a pointless downvote), I at least fixed my problem. 
My only guess it that when I was assigning a contact to null, then assigning that null value to a whitespace (" "), the program was thinking it was still technically full, since the array was now filled with unicode values for spaces ("\u0020"). So, my attempt at aesthetics in the output created a break in the program.